# UNIX/Linux shell script: Removing variant form emoji from a text

Tags: bash, shell, unicode, emoji, unicode-escapes

Consider you are using a Linux/UNIX shell whose default character set is UTF-8:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

You have a text file, emoji.txt, which is coded in UTF-8:

```
$ file -i ./emoji.txt
./emoji.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

This text file contains some emoji and a variant form escape sequence:

```
$ cat     ./emoji.txt
Standard ☁
Variant form ☁️
```

```
$ uni2ascii -a B -q ./emoji.txt
Standard \x2601
Variant form \x2601\xFE0F
```

You want to remove both emoji, including that variant form character (\xFE0F), and so the output should be

```
Standard 
Variant form
```

How would you do this?

*Update.* This question is *not* about how to remove the last word in every line. Imagine emoji2.txt that includes a large text with many emoji characters; and some of these are followed by the variant form sequence.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67495684/1836776) may also help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed` and `bash`:

```
  sed -E s/$'\u2601\uFE0F?'//g emoji.txt
```

Comment: In Z shell (zsh), replace `?` with `\?`.

Comment: @Culip You're right. It is better to put the `?` inside the `$' '` in `bash` as well. Otherwise it will be interpreted as a filename matching pattern. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`, like this:

```
$ cat emo.ascii 
Standard \x2601
Variant form \x2601\xFE0F
$ ascii2uni -a B emo.ascii                                  
Standard ☁
Variant form ☁️
3 tokens converted # note: this is stderr
$ ascii2uni -a B emo.ascii | awk -F' ' '{NF--}1' | cat -A 
3 tokens converted # note: this is stderr
Standard$
Variant form$
```

`NF--` will decrease the field count in awk, which effectively removes the last field. `1` evaluates to true, which makes awk print the modified line.

(Used `cat -A` here only to show that there aren't any invisible characters left)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Unicode text file to ASCII and remove those Unicode characters that are represented by ASCII characters, and convert it to UTF-8 again:

```
$ uni2ascii -q ./emoji.txt | sed "s/ 0x2601\(0xFE0F\)\?//g" | ascii2uni -q
Standard 
Variant form 
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Have `awk` print all but the last field:

```
$ awk '/^Standard/ || /^Variant form/ { $(NF)="" }1' emoji.txt
Standard
Variant form
```

**NOTE**: This particular solution will leave the field separator (blank) on the end of the output line; if you want to strip the trailing blank you can pipe to `sed`, `tr`, etc ... or have `awk` loop through fields 1 to (NF-1) and output via `printf`

Comment: Sorry markp-fuso, emoji.txt was just an example. Again my question is how to remove emoji with or without the variant form escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Use `nkf` command. `nkf -s` try to convert character encoding to Shift-jis which does not support emojis. Therefore, emojis and escape sequence will be gone. Finally, revert input to UTF-8 with `nkf -w`.

```
$ cat emoji.txt | nkf -s | nkf -w
Standard
Variant form

$ cat emoji.txt | nkf -s | nkf -w | od -tx1c
0000000  53  74  61  6e  64  61  72  64  20  0a  56  61  72  69  61  6e
          S   t   a   n   d   a   r   d      \n   V   a   r   i   a   n
0000020  74  20  66  6f  72  6d  20  0a
          t       f   o   r   m      \n
0000030
```

I thought `ruby` may work. Because `\p{Emoji}` matches emojis. But it remains the escape sequences..

```
$ ruby -nle 'puts $_.gsub!(/\p{Emoji}/,"")' emoji.txt
Standard
Variant form ️

$ ruby -nle 'puts $_.gsub!(/\p{Emoji}/,"")' emoji.txt | od -tx1c
0000000  53  74  61  6e  64  61  72  64  20  0a  56  61  72  69  61  6e
          S   t   a   n   d   a   r   d      \n   V   a   r   i   a   n
0000020  74  20  66  6f  72  6d  20  ef  b8  8f  0a
          t       f   o   r   m           217  \n
0000033
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't convert Unicode to Shift JIS or any character set for a specific language. The source text can include various characters such as Arabic. Coincidentally, I am a Japanese-speaker too and I would use iconv rather than nkf.

Comment: I noticed that `\p{Emoji_Component}` matches the escape sequence for emoji ([link](http://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/12.0/emoji-data.txt)). Most of the regex engines do not support it but Rust does. Install [sd](https://github.com/chmln/sd) and `sd '([^#*0-9\P{Emoji_Component}]|[^#*0-9\P{Emoji}])' '' < emoji.txt` may what you need.