# Why do Unicode emoji property escapes match numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, emoji

I found this awesome way to detect emojis using a regex that doesn't use "huge magic ranges" by using a [Unicode property escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes):

```js
console.log(/\p{Emoji}/u.test('flowers ')) // true
console.log(/\p{Emoji}/u.test('flowers')) // false
```

But when I shared this knowledge [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64007175/8186898), @Bronzdragon noticed that `\p{Emoji}` also matches numbers! Why is that? Numbers are not emojis?

```js
console.log(/\p{Emoji}/u.test('flowers 123')) // unexpectdly true

// regex-only workaround by @Bonzdragon
const regex = /(?=\p{Emoji})(?!\p{Number})/u;
console.log(
  regex.test('flowers'), // false, as expected
  regex.test('flowers 123'), // false, as expected
  regex.test('flowers 123 '), // true, as expected
  regex.test('flowers '), // true, as expected
)

// more readable workaround
const hasEmoji = str => {
  const nbEmojiOrNumber = (str.match(/\p{Emoji}/gu) || []).length;
  const nbNumber = (str.match(/\p{Number}/gu) || []).length;
  return nbEmojiOrNumber > nbNumber;
}
console.log(
  hasEmoji('flowers'), // false, as expected
  hasEmoji('flowers 123'), // false, as expected
  hasEmoji('flowers 123 '), // true, as expected
  hasEmoji('flowers '), // true, as expected
)
```

Comment: Note that the workaround also fails for '123 flowers ' for example - that *should* return true, as it definitely has emoji.

Comment: why not just remove all numbers then do the check?

Comment: The question is not how to fix it ([here is a fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48148218/3832970)), the question is **why**. Else, let's close it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew indeed, I am asking **why**, also I don't want to use one of these range-based regex because they're extremely long, unreadable, magic, and not resilient to the adding of new emojis

Comment: I think the answer is [here](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex/issues/33#issuecomment-373674579) and all thread after that post. *This is not a bug. `#` and `0-9` are `Emoji` characters with a text representation by default, per the Unicode Standard.*

Comment: [This post](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex/issues/33#issuecomment-374176872) goes into more detail and you probably can use the `/\p{Extended_Pictographic}/u` regex to match emojis except for some keycap base characters that are still emojis.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [this post](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex/issues/33#issuecomment-374176872), digtis, `#`, `*`, ZWJ and some more chars contain the `Emoji` property set to *Yes*, which means **digits are considered valid emoji chars**:

```
0023          ; Emoji_Component      #  1.1  [1] (#️)       number sign
002A          ; Emoji_Component      #  1.1  [1] (*️)       asterisk
0030..0039    ; Emoji_Component      #  1.1 [10] (0️..9️)    digit zero..digit nine
200D          ; Emoji_Component      #  1.1  [1] (‍)        zero width joiner
20E3          ; Emoji_Component      #  3.0  [1] (⃣)       combining enclosing keycap
FE0F          ; Emoji_Component      #  3.2  [1] ()        VARIATION SELECTOR-16
1F1E6..1F1FF  ; Emoji_Component      #  6.0 [26] (..)    regional indicator symbol letter a..regional indicator symbol letter z
1F3FB..1F3FF  ; Emoji_Component      #  8.0  [5] (..)    light skin tone..dark skin tone
1F9B0..1F9B3  ; Emoji_Component      # 11.0  [4] (..)    red-haired..white-haired
E0020..E007F  ; Emoji_Component      #  3.1 [96] (..)      tag space..cancel tag
```

For example, `1` is a digit, but it becomes an emoji when combined with `U+FE0F` and `U+20E3` chars: 1️⃣:

```js
console.log("1\uFE0F\u20E3 2\uFE0F\u20E3 3\uFE0F\u20E3 4\uFE0F\u20E3 5\uFE0F\u20E3 6\uFE0F\u20E3 7\uFE0F\u20E3 8\uFE0F\u20E3 9\uFE0F\u20E3 0\uFE0F\u20E3")
```

If you want to avoid matching digits, use `Extended_Pictographic` Unicode category class:

> The Extended_Pictographic characters contain all the Emoji characters except for some Emoji_Components.

So, you may use either `/\p{Extended_Pictographic}/gu` to most emojis proper, or `/\p{Extended_Pictographic}/u` to test for a single emoji proper, or use `/[\p{Extended_Pictographic}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B3}]/u` to match emojis proper and light skin to dark skin mode chars and red-haired to white-haired chars:

```js
const regex_emoji = /[\p{Extended_Pictographic}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B3}]/u;
console.log( regex_emoji.test('flowers 123') );     // => false
console.log( regex_emoji.test('flowers ') ); // => true
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort on the answer, if you could tell me **why** the unicode consortion considers 0123456789#* as emojis that'd be perfect!

Comment: @NinoFiliu I added a demo showing how `1` turns into an emoji.

Comment: Note that if you use this regex to remove emojis from strings (e.g. `'❌‍♀️‍♂️'.replace(/[\p{Extended_Pictographic}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}\u{1F9B0}-\u{1F9B3}]/gu, '')`), there will be some leftover characters in the string (above resulting string has length 4). For this use case, I ended up using the [`emoji-regex`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-regex) npm package to match them.

Comment: @Thai I have an all-embracing regex for [Emojis V14.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48148218/3832970), but I need to update it for the [current 15.1](https://unicode.org/Public/draft/emoji/emoji-test.txt). This answer is more about the `\p{Emoji}` construct. People just freak out when they see long regex patterns, so I tried to come up with something based on the Unicode category classes that is short and good enough.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I agree, I think your solution is short and good enough for checking for the presence of emojis in a string. Furthermore, your answer is relevant to the question (you answered why) while mine isn’t (I suggested an npm package for a particular use case). However, I added the comment above here because this StackOverflow post came up first on Google when I try to debug the problem where `.replace(/\p{Emoji}/gu, '')` deleted the numbers.

Comment: one way to think about this is that `\p{Emoji}` means "can this ever be part of an emoji" not "is this always an emoji". so it would be useful for eg checking whether a string is _entirely_ composed of emoji

Answer (score 5):

One of the problems with using `\p{Emoji}` is that Unicode defines `Emoji` as a *character property*, meaning it only captures individual characters or code points. As a result, `\p{Emoji}` might seem to solve your problem as long as you only test it against single-code point emoji such as  (U+1FAF1), but that’s misleading.

However, the vast majority of emoji defined by Unicode consist of multiple code points, and thus cannot be matched by `\p{Emoji}`. For example: ‍ (U+1FAF1 U+1F3FF U+200D U+1FAF2 U+1F3FB).

```js
const reEmojiCharacter = /^\p{Emoji}$/u;
reEmojiCharacter.test(''); // → true
reEmojiCharacter.test('‍'); // → false
```

Luckily, Unicode defines several *properties of strings*, which — you guessed it — are not restricted to just 1 code point at a time. The property of strings called `RGI_Emoji` includes all emoji that are officially recommended for general interchange, and is likely what you really want instead of `Emoji`.

In JavaScript regular expressions, you can use properties of strings when enabling [the `v` flag](https://v8.dev/features/regexp-v-flag).

```js
const reEmoji = /^\p{RGI_Emoji}$/v;
reEmoji.test(''); // → true
reEmoji.test('‍'); // → true
```

Comment: Nice catch! I added your answer as a "see also" link of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64007175/8186898)